# memory leak in malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I've got the following faulty piece of code in C and I am wondering if there will be a memory leak or if there will be a pointer which is pointing to a free memory location.

```
int* p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
p = NULL;
free(p);
```

Comment: This will indeed lead to a memory leak. ```p``` is no longer pointing to the allocated memory chunk (and neither is anything else), so you cannot free it.

Comment: You never free it so you leak it. It has nothing to do with malloc, though.

Comment: You also don't need to cast `malloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will leak memory. You assign p to NULL before freeing the contents it's pointing to. One quick change will fix it:

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

The difference here is we give free the address allocated by malloc before setting p to NULL. In general setting a pointer to NULL will not free the contents, but will allow you to check if the pointer is valid or not which can have a lot of practical applications.

Comment: you don't need to cast `malloc`, this is C.

Comment: I just copied their code. I'll do some other cleanup and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a memory leak.

After you assign `NULL` to `p`, you no longer have a way to refer to the memory you allocated with `malloc`.

Your call to `free` will try to free `NULL`, doing nothing.

The following will correctly free the memory:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Note that you don't need to set `p` to `NULL` after freeing, you only really need the first two lines.